Charon plugins eap-mschapv2 is not loading
sudo charon-cmd
00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon-cmd ldap pkcs11 aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 rdrand random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 sshkey pem gcrypt af-alg fips-prf gmp chapoly xcbc hmac ctr ccm ntru drbg curl kernel-libipsec kernel-netlink resolve socket-default bypass-lan eap-identity eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap

cat /etc/strongswan.d/charon/eap-mschapv2.conf 
eap-mschapv2 {

    # Whether to load the plugin. Can also be an integer to increase the
    # priority of this plugin.
    load = yes

}


